# Cannot mount dvd/cd in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, cd-drive

I am trying to make my own game server of perfect world and for that i need to Mount the server Files that are on my DVD. But i am using the command mount/dev/cdrom/cdrom it is not mounting saying already exists. I tried making a symbolic link.. but can't really find what to do. Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

There must be something wrong in translation. What command did you use to mount it? It should be:

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

cdroms are also usually sr devices under /dev, i.e. sr0, sr1, so if the above command doesn't work, try

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
```

If you are still having trouble, make sure the folder /media/cdrom exists and give us the output of

```
mount
```