# How to mount a CD/DVD in DOSBOX?

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd, dosbox

I'm using `DOSBox 0.74`, which works properly and can successfully mount a "c" drive.  However, I don't know how to mount a dvd drive.  I'm trying to install *Star Control 3* from a disk so that I can play it with DOSBox, but I can't mount the "d" drive.  I've tried `mount d /media/cdrom0 -t cdrom` which http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-auto-mount-a-drive-in-dosbox.html claimed would work.  I've looked at http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/MOUNT#Linux but I didn't understand what exactly it was saying.

So I guess what I'm really asking is does anyone know what commands to use to mount a CD/DVD using DOSBox in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Is your CD/DVD drive mounted at `/media/cdrom0` in your "outer" Ubuntu system? I've only used CDs in DOSBox on an OSX host (my Ubuntu system has no CD/DVD drive), but my leftover config files all have normal folder paths in the `mount` commands rather than devices. Since that tutorial is almost 6 years old, it's possible that the mount point convention has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you really have the CD/DVD mounted on that location, as usually the CD label is used instead, then run:

```
mount d /media/LABEL -t cdrom -label LABEL -ioctl -usecd 0
```

Just replace LABEL with whatever you have.
Tested it on Dosbox 0.74 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: When I type `mount d /media/STARCON3 -t cdrom -label STARCON3 -ioctl -usecd 0` I get the same "Directory /media/STARCON3 doesn't exist"  Am I still missing something?

Comment: That is all. Worked for me. It is case sensitive. You could try adding an extra slash /media/STARCON3/ or quotes "/media/STARCON3/"

Comment: I've tried `mount d /media/STARCON3/ -t cdrom -label STARCON3 -ioctl -usecd 0` and `mount d "/media/STARCON3/" -t cdrom -label STARCON3 -ioctl -usecd 0` and `mount d /media/STARCON3/` as well as `mount d "/media/STARCON3/" and I still get the `Directory /media/STARCON3/ doesn't exist.`  I'm thinking now that perhaps I don't have the correct name for my DVD drive, is there any way to check that?

Comment: Type `mount` and you should see where it mounted your CD. Sometimes it is mounted on `/media/user/label/`. If is not present, try mounting it manually or check the following posts. [Cannot mount DVD/CD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140399/cannot-mount-dvd-cd-in-ubuntu-10-04) [How to find mount point](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102406/how-to-find-mount-point-for-audio-cd-dvd)

Comment: looking at the output of `mount` in the terminal gave me exactly what I needed, thanks!