# How to mount a CD in Dosbox using 18.04?

Tags: mount, dvd, cd

I've been trying to mount a CD in Dosbox unsuccessfully after having followed various threads out there.

The problem seems to be not recognizing the directory where my CD is. When I look at the location of the CD, it states `/media/andrew/CM` (Championship Manager 2 game) so I've tried `/media/CM`, `/media/andrew/CM` etc., but always states the directory doesn't exist.

Any ideas please?

Comment: For games you may have luck with mounting the CD ISO with CDemu as `/dev/srX` see https://askubuntu.com/questions/278912/mount-an-iso-image-in-wine

Comment: Thanks but I think it's a specific Dosbox problem.

Comment: Is this any help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/305030/how-to-mount-a-cd-dvd-in-dosbox it does look like it only mentions things which I'd assume to be obvious.

Comment: Thanks I followed that and still same, don't think I'm daft but must be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make a disk image from the CD, then:

Manually:

> dosbox -c "imgmount D [isoList] -t iso" [exe] -fullscreen -exit

Automatically:

- [exeCute](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/exeCute)